# Directly play input sound (Mint)

Tags: linux-mint, audio, output, input

I recently set up a Linux Mint 18 machine, which has an electric piano plugged into it via a USB sound card.

Now, the input works: we can record sounds from the piano; and the output works as we can play them back, but is there a tweak or a program that will allow us to hear the input as it is played?

Answer (score -1):

If recording with [Audacity](https://audacityteam.org), yes, you can!

Select **Preferences**, then the **Audio I/O** tab, then turn on **Software Playthrough**.
Click in the right-hand recording VU meter with the microphone symbol to toggle monitoring on/off.